# How can I improve the ScreenRecord quality in Android?

Tags: android, adb, android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to record the screen of my android phone using the ScreenRecord feature of the ADB. I do this via AndroidStudio but I doubt that it makes a difference if I use it from the console.

Regardless of the quality settings (the screenshot below is from a video with 20Mbps datarate at FullHD), the videos lacks lots of colors and the text looks awful.

[image: Left side: Screenshot, right side: video]

Am I missing something? Or is the quality simply limited to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out, that this is not an issue related to ADB, my phone or AndroidStudio but rather of my system. Playing the video files on another computer solves the problem. Maybe this is an encoding issue.

Comment: OK, I would have suggested to use mobizen otherwise. If I am allowed to make advertise for them here.

Comment: I'll take a lookt at it, but I doubt it will solve the problem ;)

Comment: You can edit the screenshot and video quality settings there. Hope it helps!